# Avoid the user to click the Windows start button in the taskbar after login

Tags: windows, permissions, shell, taskbar, login

After the user logs in on Windows 10, explorer.exe is loaded. The Windows Start button in the taskbar is visible and clickable.

Any script or executable ran at startup to hide the taskbar, does so too late. For one or two seconds, the user can click the button.

I tried running things from the start up folder, didn't work. I tried preventing all input from mouse for ten seconds, same thing happens, it blocks input too late.

I tried with the task scheduler using triggers like at system start, at user logon, at session login. The user is in administrators group and has batch login permissions on policy manager. Does not work.

I was thinking of replacing the shell with a program that places an unmoveable dialog on that part of the screen and make it topmost, and then launches explorer.exe but I suspect this will not work, as ui programs need explorer.exe.

Is there any solution to this? Obviously auto-hide taskbar is also not good enough.

Kiosk mode is not an option.

This hides the taskbar, is there a way to do something like this from the very instant or before the user logs in?

#include <windows.h>

```
int main() {
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(L"Shell_traywnd", L"");
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) {
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, on Group Policy manager I'm able to disable the win keyboard buttons, so that's already fixed.

Comment: Can you explain what the user needs to be able/unable to do? There are policy settings to strip everything out of the start menu or taskbar, like https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.StartMenu::NoRun . Why is Kiosk mode not an option? You can assign multiple applications for kiosks in newer versions of win10

Comment: Disable USB devices, then enable them after the start button has been hidden? https://www.intowindows.com/2-ways-to-hide-or-remove-start-button-in-windows-10/ ?